# Python: How to draw railroads form geography t-sql data type?

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

I try create a railways roads on map, from created DF in SQL. My geography date type for row looks like that:
0xE610000001041E000000F0C12630B2AF4A4080DB399F

Is any libary or solution to draw line from this form on folium?

Comment: Please read [How to ask)(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what is your current data structure, but seeing as you tagged it 'geopandas' I will asume geodataframe is what you have.

In that case just do `gdf.plot()`, where "gdf" is your geodataframe.

You can read more about plotting geodataframes in documentation: http://geopandas.org/mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes i try geopandas but i got output "no numeric data to plot"
When i convert this Series on SQL i got this type of new series:

LINESTRING (14.663655258000063 53.372625369000...

and still this same answer. I try this:

railInput=pd.read_csv('file.csv', use_cols='geo')
railInput.plot()